Clarification of detecting reed solomon error locations when more than t errors have occured
There is the question below that goes into some detail on Reed Solomon decoding when there are more than $t$ errors and the Reed Solomon is setup as $RS(n, n-2t)$, but I'm hoping I can get a little more clarification.
Unambiguously detecting (not correcting) between $t+1$ and $2t$ errors in a Reed-Solomon message
I've read a few different things which are probably all the same, but I'm interpreting differently. I've read that RS can detect up to $2t$ errors, but can detect and correct $t$ errors, but then I'll see other places where if there are more than $t$ errors, that you'll just know that you have too many errors to correct and that's about it. The above link makes it seem like there is a way of finding where those up to $2t$ error locations might be, but it might be very computationally expensive.
I've also seen an article where if you have $2s+r < 2t$ where $s$ is the number of errors and $r$ is the number of known erasure locations, then you can decode the code word.
So do you need to know the erasure locations already in order to to know the error locations when you have more then $t$ errors? I haven't found anything yet that shows how to actually find the error locations when you have between $t$ and $2t$ errors. Is there a good algorithm that can find this that I could be pointed towards, or is it that I'm miss understanding a critical point somewhere?

Your question, covering both error correction and errors-and-erasures decoding is too broad. It will require a significant part of a chapter of a book to answer properly.
